# Need to create a html page for adding X days to D.O.B

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a HTML code that adds a fixed number of days to an entered Date of Birth. Thanks a lot! Even a partial code is much appreciated!

Comment: You can't do this in HTML. You need at least javascript or server side code like php/c# etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it. The function daysFromDate returns a Date object you can use. Instead of passing the DOB as a string you can also update it to use a Date object.

```
/* 
    days is the number of days to add, and dob a string like "4/24/2011"
*/

function daysFromDate(days, dob) {
    var dates = dob.split('/');
    var daysToMilli = days * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000; 

    var d = new Date(parseInt(dates[2]), parseInt(dates[0])-1, parseInt(dates[1]));
    var newTime = d.getTime() + daysToMilli;

    return new Date(newTime);
}
```

To get the date 20 days from now you call: `daysFromDate(20, "4/24/2011");`

Comment: Thanks much! How do I integrate the script in my html file. Thank you!

Comment: In a script tag on your HTML file. This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) could be useful.

Comment: I mean, if I have a text box which has the DOB and a result box which this script throws the result into, how is that done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VBScript has DateAdd() so it's pretty simple.  If you prefer JavaScript, just Google "javascript dateAdd" -- there are a zillion solutions out there.  Here's one:
http://www.solutionbot.com/2008/06/20/javascript-dateadd-function/